# Getting this error on updating multipicklist field using flow:- INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST: bad value for restricted picklist field

Tags: visual-workflow, multi-select, duplicate-value

I am trying to update a multipicklist field on Accounts using the multipicklist field on Opportunity, which is also using the same global picklist value set. But I am facing two problems with this:-

1. I am getting an error because of this flow when I try to save a record on Opportunity-- attached a screenshot (This error occurred when the flow tried to update records: INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST: bad value for restricted picklist field:). And also this is not happening for all the picklist values, it occurs for only few set of picklist values.
2. I am getting duplicate values in multipicklist field on Accounts after the flow is executed as there are multiple Opportunity for an Account. I tried to get rid of that by using decision element that doesn't seem to work.

Pls feel free to ask me anything, if something doesn't make sense.

[image: Storing Multipicklist values into variable]

[image: Error on saving opportunity record caused because of the flow]

[image: Decision element used to not store duplicate values to variable]

Comment: Now I am able to get rid of the "INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST" error. But still I need help with the duplicate values being stored on the multiselectpicklist field -- what I want is to remove duplicate values from the text variable which is updating the multiselect picklist using flow.

Answer (score 2):

Possible causes of the error you are getting:

- The value "FF Billing" does not exist on the picklist field.
- The value "FF Billing" does exist but is not available on the record type of the record that is being updated.
- The value "FF Billing" belongs to a dependant picklist and the controlling picklist is not being set.

Comment: Thank you! for sharing this. For me the thing which worked was checking the record type on the Accounts object, I found those values where not present in selected values, so just  moved these values to this column.

But still I am not able to resolve the duplicate values being stored on multiselect picklist:- so what I want is to remove duplicate values from the text variable which is updating the multiselect picklist.

Answer (score 0):

## INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST: bad value for restricted picklist field

this above error says that you are trying to update the picklist with a value that does is not there in its metadata or to be more precise not present in its value metadata that is defined under the Object

Answer (score -1):

you will need to check if your test variable where you are storing your MVP values contains the incoming value for each opportunity record for each value in the opportunity MVP field. My guess is that you already have the 2 loops to do this, you just need to check if your text varialble "Contrains" the value you are trying to insert, and if it is already there skip that value.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that this is an answer to _this_ question.